# Recommendations for text classification models to work with almost 200K labels

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp

So basically I want to classify a lot of labels (200K+).
Are there any recommended models I should try in order to have a relatively good accuracy and not take days to complete?

I have tried to use Sklearn's OneVsRestClassifier for LinearRegression, and I left it overnight and the fitting still didn't finish

I believe that there should be more efficient algorithms for multiclass classification for NLP

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO; please do take some time to read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and notice that questions asking us to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource* are off-topic for SO.

Answer (score -1):

Given the amount of data that you have available, consider multinomial Naive Bayes. Sklearn has a very straight forward implementation of this: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB.html
This will be quicker than using a neural network. A lot of training data on a simple model will always have more predictive power than a larger model with less data.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I will try it